# Return a Bitmap from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, bitmap

I have two forms, form one handles the image compression and form two handles the details.
Details like; browse for a bitmap, image quality and a save file name.

The problem i am having at the moment is the bitmap is returning to form one as null.
This then produces the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Where abouts is the problem?
Ive been staring at the screen too long and another pair of eyes could really help.

Code Form1:

```
    public void compressImg(Bitmap bitmp, string fileName, int quality)
            {

                //string fileName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter a file name:", "Save File", "JPEGCompress", 250, 250);

                ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
                ImageCodecInfo ici = null;

                foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
                {
                    if (codec.MimeType == "image/jpeg")
                        ici = codec;
                }



                EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters();
                ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, (long)quality);
                bitmp.Save("C:\\" + fileName + ".jpg", ici, ep);

            }

 private void compressAnImageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                string fileName;
                int quality;
                Bitmap bitmp;

                Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                f2.ShowDialog();
                fileName = f2.getFileName;
                quality = f2.getQuality;
                bitmp = f2.getBtmap;

                //Bitmap newbitmp = new Bitmap(bitmp);

                compressImg(bitmp, fileName, quality);

            }
```

Code Form2:

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        public static string fileName;
        public static int quality;
        public Bitmap bitmp, bitmap1;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public string getFileName
        {          
            get { return fileName; }
            set { fileName = txtFileName.Text; }
        }

        public int getQuality
        {
            get { return quality; }
            set { quality = imgQualTrkBar.Value; }
        }

        private void BtnSubmitInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                bitmp = new Bitmap(openFileDialog2.FileName);

            }
        }

        public Bitmap getBtmap
        {
            get { return bitmap1; }
            set { bitmap1 = new Bitmap(bitmp); }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It would not appear the you are not setting your getBtmap property in form 2 anywhere so bitmap1 will always be null.

Comment: I can't see anywhere the call that set the value of bitmap1.

Comment: Apologies, been staring at code all day. Simple things seem so complicated. Thanks for all the help. Error fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your error is because you're storing your `Bitmap` object in `bitmp`.. but returning `bitmap1` from your `getBtmap` property.

Also, you've called your properties `getSomething` when they also have set accessors that don't accept a value. This will confuse you (as will your variable names.. consider renaming them too).

Consider this:

```
frm.getFileName = "MY FILE NAME";
```

..that doesn't store "MY FILE NAME".. it stores the textbox value. Consider changing this logic.